# How to find if a given key exists in a std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, stdmap

I'm trying to check if a given key is in a map and somewhat can't do it:

```
typedef map<string,string>::iterator mi;
map<string, string> m;
m.insert(make_pair("f","++--"));
pair<mi,mi> p = m.equal_range("f");//I'm not sure if equal_range does what I want
cout << p.first;//I'm getting error here
```

so how can I print what is in p?

Answer (score 977, accepted):

Use [`map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and [`map::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end):

```
if (m.find("f") == m.end()) {
  // not found
} else {
  // found
}
```

Comment: If you just want to check whether a certain key exists, you'd probably rather use [`map::count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/)

Comment: @tomsmeding There is only a single key in a std::map. So count will either be 0 or 1. Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: @goelakash hardly; it's just that `count` returns an `int` while `find` returns a whole iterator. You save the construction of the iterator :) Obviously, if you afterwards are going to *use* the value if it exists, use find and store its result.

Comment: @tomsmeding If you're using a multimap, you'd have to look through the entire container.  In which case, find() may be quicker.

Comment: what is its time compelxity. Will it be linear as the method will iterate through the whole map

Comment: @NikhilRathore The time complexity of std::map::find and ::count are both logarithmic because it is an [ordered map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), which does not have to test every item in the map. The time complexity of std::unordered_map::find and ::count are ['kind of' constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1) to understand why I say 'kind of'). This is because it uses a hash table which allows it to often jump straight to the correct memory location.

Comment: **To those who are looking for speed:** `count` and `find` are nearly identical in speed when using maps that require unique keys. (1) If you don't need the elements to maintain a specific order, use [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which has [near-constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771368/) look-ups and can be very beneficial when storing more than a few pairs. (2) If you want to use the value if it exists, store the result of ::find and use the iterator to prevent 2 look-ups: `auto it = m.find("f"); if (it != m.end()) {/*Use it->second*/}`

Answer (score 397):

To check if a particular key in the map exists, use the `count` member function in one of the following ways:

```
m.count(key) > 0
m.count(key) == 1
m.count(key) != 0
```

The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) for `map::find` says: "Another member function, `map::count`, can be used to just check whether a particular key exists."

The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) for `map::count` says: "Because all elements in a map container are unique, the function can only return 1 (if the element is found) or zero (otherwise)."

To retrieve a value from the map via a key that you know to exist, use [map::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/):

```
value = m.at(key)
```

Unlike [map::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/), `map::at` will not create a new key in the map if the specified key does not exist.

Comment: If you are going to do both operations, check if it exists and then do something about it. Use `find` instead. The `second` attribute of the iterator returned by `find` can be used retrieve the value of the key. If you use `count` then `at` or `operator[]` you are performing two operations when you could have used only one.

Comment: You don't need to do > 0, == 1 or != 0; that's the exact check C++ does in an if statement (condition != 0), so you can just use `if(m.count(key))`

Comment: @jv110 The Microsoft C++ compiler [issues a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968033/1497596) when it encounters a cast from `int` to `bool`. Though there are other C++ compilers that do not issue a similar warning, I prefer using an [explicit comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968060/1497596) to make the intent clear and enhance readability. Note that other languages such as C# [forbid such an implicit conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571505/1497596) to prevent the possibility of introducing subtle programming errors.

Comment: what is time complexity of count? Is it just O(1) operation?

Comment: @Mazeryt Given that we are talking about a class in the C++ standard library, I would certainly assume so. For a language-agnostic discussion of your question, see [Can hash tables really be O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368).

Comment: @Mazeryt No, `std::map::count` is actually [logarithmic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count). This is because [C++ std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is an ordered map, so it does not use a hash table. However, the C++ standard library also has `std::unordered_map`, where `std::unordered_map::count` is [O(1) often](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count). See [DavidRR's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1) to know why even std::unordered_map::count is not always O(1).

Comment: I like this one more than the find() thingy - it's way more expressive

Comment: I don't get the `m.count(key) > 0` case. A map is an associative array that is a dictionary. Keys are unique hence you cannot have multiple equivalent keys (obviously does not apply to the values associated with those).

Answer (score 184):

**C++20** gives us `std::map::contains` to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> example = {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}, 
                                     {3, "Three"}, {42, "Don\'t Panic!!!"}};

    if(example.contains(42)) {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Good thing I scrolled down here. Maybe edit the accepted answer and add it to it?

Answer (score 57):

You can use `.find()`:

```
map<string,string>::iterator i = m.find("f");

if (i == m.end()) { /* Not found */ }
else { /* Found, i->first is f, i->second is ++-- */ }
```

Answer (score 48):

C++17 simplified this a bit more with an *If statement with initializer*.
This way you can have your cake and eat it too.

```
if ( auto it{ m.find( "key" ) }; it != std::end( m ) ) 
{
    // Use `structured binding` to get the key
    // and value.
    const auto&[ key, value ] { *it };

    // Grab either the key or value stored in the pair.
    // The key is stored in the 'first' variable and
    // the 'value' is stored in the second.
    const auto& mkey{ it->first };
    const auto& mvalue{ it->second };

    // That or just grab the entire pair pointed
    // to by the iterator.
    const auto& pair{ *it };
} 
else 
{
   // Key was not found..
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
m.find == m.end() // not found
```

If you want to use other API, then find go for `m.count(c)>0`

```
 if (m.count("f")>0)
      cout << " is an element of m.\n";
    else 
      cout << " is not an element of m.\n";
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you want `map::find`. If `m.find("f")` is equal to `m.end()`, then the key was not found. Otherwise, find returns an iterator pointing at the element found.

The error is because `p.first` is an iterator, which doesn't work for stream insertion. Change your last line to `cout << (p.first)->first;`. `p` is a pair of iterators, `p.first` is an iterator, `p.first->first` is the key string.

A map can only ever have one element for a given key, so `equal_range` isn't very useful. It's defined for map, because it's defined for all associative containers, but it's a lot more interesting for multimap.

Comment: Actually, because it is a pair of iterators to a map, it should be "cout << p.first->first;"

Comment: I've fixed my answer, thanks. That's what I get for not compiling my code. And you're right (in a deleted comment) about checking for validity, but I was just trying to explain why he couldn't print p.first, and it's not because it's invalid - we know "f" will be found. Since I don't recommend using equal_range at all, I'm not about to show error-checking code for that.

Comment: Wow, you're really scanning SO.  I was just adding it for completeness, because your point was clear.  I added the validity check to my previous answer, but your response beated me, so I deleted it, because it didn't add that much anyway, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

```
template <typename T, typename Key>
bool key_exists(const T& container, const Key& key)
{
    return (container.find(key) != std::end(container));
}
```

Of course if you wanted to get fancier you could always template out a function that also took a found function and a not found function, something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Key, typename FoundFunction, typename NotFoundFunction>
void find_and_execute(const T& container, const Key& key, FoundFunction found_function, NotFoundFunction not_found_function)
{
    auto& it = container.find(key);
    if (it != std::end(container))
    {
        found_function(key, it->second);
    }
    else
    {
        not_found_function(key);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    std::map<int, int> some_map;
    find_and_execute(some_map, 1,
        [](int key, int value){ std::cout << "key " << key << " found, value: " << value << std::endl; },
        [](int key){ std::cout << "key " << key << " not found" << std::endl; });
```

The downside to this is coming up with a good name, "find_and_execute" is awkward and I can't come up with anything better off the top of my head...

Answer (score 6):

```
map<string, string> m;
```

check key exist or not, and return number of occurs(0/1 in map):

```
int num = m.count("f");  
if (num>0) {    
    //found   
} else {  
    // not found  
}
```

check key exist or not, and return iterator:

```
map<string,string>::iterator mi = m.find("f");  
if(mi != m.end()) {  
    //found  
    //do something to mi.  
} else {  
    // not found  
}
```

---

in your question, the error caused by bad `operator<<` overload, because `p.first` is `map<string, string>`, you can not print it out. try this:

```
if(p.first != p.second) {
    cout << p.first->first << " " << p.first->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo. Change "cout" to "count"

Comment: And that typo can really throw someone off, as the `cout` can mean something very different than `count`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful in comparing the find result with the the end like for map 'm' as all answer have 
done above
     map::iterator i = m.find("f");

```
 if (i == m.end())
 {
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

you should not try and perform any operation such as printing the key or value with iterator i if its equal to m.end() else it will lead to segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the code of std::map::find and std::map::count, I'd say the first may yield some performance advantage:

```
const_iterator find(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find an element in nonmutable sequence that matches _Keyval
    const_iterator _Where = lower_bound(_Keyval); // Here one looks only for lower bound
    return (_Where == end()
        || _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(),
            _Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode()))
                ? end() : _Where);
    }

size_type count(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // count all elements that match _Keyval
    _Paircc _Ans = equal_range(_Keyval); // Here both lower and upper bounds are to be found, which is presumably slower.
    size_type _Num = 0;
    _Distance(_Ans.first, _Ans.second, _Num);
    return (_Num);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question already has some good answers but I think my solution is worth of sharing.

It works for both `std::map` and `std::vector<std::pair<T, U>>` and is available from C++11.

```cpp
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Key>
bool contains_key(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Key const key) {
    using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type;

    auto search_result = std::find_if(
        first, last,
        [&key](ValueType const& item) {
            return item.first == key;
        }
    );

    if (search_result == last) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both [find()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and [contains()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) can be used. According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Both methods take constant time on average and linear time in the worst case.

Answer (score -7):

```
map <int , char>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = MyMap.begin() ; itr!= MyMap.end() ; itr++)
    {
        if (itr->second == 'c')
        {
            cout<<itr->first<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your code. A snippet without any explanation doesn't tend to be helpful in a long run.

Answer (score -8):

If you want to compare pair of map you can use this method:

```
typedef map<double, double> TestMap;
TestMap testMap;
pair<map<double,double>::iterator,bool> controlMapValues;

controlMapValues= testMap.insert(std::pair<double,double>(x,y));
if (controlMapValues.second == false )
{
    TestMap::iterator it;
    it = testMap.find(x);

    if (it->second == y)
    {
        cout<<"Given value is already exist in Map"<<endl;
    }
}
```

This is a useful technique.

Comment: As beginner with C++ programming, I'm really curious why this answer is downvoted. Why is this answer unpopular?

Comment: @gromit190 because it's using a whole other data structure to see if the key exists when std::map has this capability already.  This would also require synchronisation between the two data structures which is a dependency no one wants to deal with.