# Get cumulative value from a List of Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, dictionary

I have a `List` of `Map<String, Integer>` . Each `Map` instance contain the productName as key, product price as value.

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> products = GET_ALL_PRODUCTS();
```

For example the List could contain Maps with the following data :

Map 1:

```
"prod1" : 10
"prod2" : 5
"prod3" : 2
```

Map 2:

```
"prod3" : 3
"prod4" : 6
```

Map 3:

```
"prod1" : 12
"prod4" : 8
```

I need to generate a new `Map<String, Integer>` which contains productName as key still, but with the cumulative amount of price for each product as value. That is:

**new Map** should contain:

```
"prod1" : 10+12
"prod2" : 5
"prod3" : 2+3
"prod4" : 6+8
```

I ended up with the following code, I am wondering what is the **most efficient way** to generate this new `Map`??

```
Map<String, Integer> cumulativeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i=0; i< products.size(); i++){
    Map<String, Integer> product = products.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> products = new ArrayList<>();
//Add products Maps here 

Map<String, Integer> cumulativeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// Use enhaced for loop for efficiency.
for(Map<String, Integer> productMap: products){
  for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> p: productMap.entrySet()){

   if(cumulativeMap.containsKey(p.getKey())){
      cumulativeMap.put(p.getKey(), cumulativeMap.get(p.getKey())+ p.getValue());
   }
   else{
     cumulativeMap.put(p.getKey(),  p.getValue());
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it more efficient than the index-based loop?

Comment: You should avoid calling `get` inside a loop, @aga. Utilizing `Map.Entry<K,V>` should be preferred.

Comment: @predi so, the time complexity of `HashMap.get` method is `O(N)`, right?

Comment: No, it's not more efficient than the index-based loop, unless the `List` is `LinkedList` or something like this. An `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccessList` and so the indexed access must be faster *per definition*. However, the difference is most probably negligible. and using the for-each loop is more readable.

Comment: @aga, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity).

Comment: @aga: No, the time complexity of `HashMap.get` is `O(1)` assuming the `hashCode` works well. It can get as bad as `O(N)` in pathological cases only. However, by using the `entrySet` you save the access.

Comment: @predi, okay, it's `O(1)`, but it tends to be equal `O(N)` in some particular cases. now I understand. thanks for the explanation!