# What algorithm does java contains() method use?

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

I want to search efficiently for an object in a HashSet that I have.

I would like to know if the contains() method which is defined on java collections uses binary search or not? Or should I write my own binary search algorithm?

Comment: you can see the source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashSet.contains performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247854/hashset-contains-performance)

Comment: "HashSet" and "binary search" won't fit together. Reason: binary search requires a sorted (and thus ordered) collection while _hash_ sets are unordered by definition.

Comment: "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets."

Comment: `HashSet` isn't ordered, so you'll have trouble running a binary-search. The way `contains()` works : it calculates the "fingerprint" of the `contains()` argument. It then checks if it knows this fingerprint. Done.

Comment: The "fingerprint", to be clear, is the `equals` comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general search complexity in a `HashSet` is `O(1)` - meaning it is constant. Writing your own? Better then this?

You absolutely can look at the sources, understand that a `HashSet` is actually a `HashMap` internally; that it uses buckets and LinkedNodes and TreeNodes; understand how these work, etc etc. Or *trust* the implementation that is good and focus on other stuff; unless you honestly have a requirement for something faster.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I find what you have said useful. I am using hashsets to store some objects retrieved from a database. Sometimes I want to check if a certain object is within the set. From what you have mentioned, the contains() method should suit my purposes.