# Java List contains element of another list of a different type

Tags: java, list, contain

I would like to ask if there is a better way of find if a List contains at least one element of another List of a different type.

For instance

```
public class AnotherType{
  private int x;
  private String label;
  ....
}


List<String> list1 = new ArrayLis<String>();
list1.add("inst1");
list1.add("inst2");
list1.add("inst3");
List<AnotherType> list2 = new ArrayList<AnotherType>();
list2.add(new AnotherType(1,"inst7"));
list2.add(new AnotherType(1,"inst1"));
```

Now I want to find that the `list2` in the index 1(second element) contains the element "inst1" that exists in `list1`.
Is that a better than make one loop inside the other?
I work with java 1.6

Comment: Streams would be good at this. Why Java 6? It's 3 major versions behind.

Comment: Just iterate through list 1 and as soon as you find an element that is also in list 2, break. What have you tried? How do you define "better"?

Comment: You could create a `Map<String, AnotherType>` if `inst7` etc is unique.
Alternatively `Map<String, List<AnotherType>>`.

Comment: If `inst`s are unique, and you do not care about the order of `list1`, you could model it as a `HashSet`, after which `list1.contains()` would be much less time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you represent `list1` as a HashSet, the `.contains()` operation would be much faster, [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247854/hashset-contains-performance), as compared to `ArrayList.contains()`, which would be `O(n)`.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayLis<String>();
list1.add("inst1");
list1.add("inst2");
list1.add("inst3");

List<AnotherType> list2 = new ArrayList<AnotherType>();
list2.add(new AnotherType(1,"inst7"));
list2.add(new AnotherType(1,"inst1"));

Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);

for(AnotherType elem : list2) {
     if(set1.contains(elem.getLabel())) {
         //  Do your thing here.
         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
for( final AnotherType item : list2 )
{
  if ( list1.contains(item.getLabel() )
  {
    // TODO what do you want to do with the found items?
  }
}
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question of "is there a better way than making one loop inside the other?"

Comment: You don't appear to have actually explained why your way is better. It's just a code dump.