# how can I reduce my list of structures based on the other list of Strings in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

In my `Java` application I have a class:

```
public class MyStructure {

    SomeClass someClass;
    String[] fields;

    ...
}
```

Now, I have a list of the structures above:

```
List< MyStructure> structures = getStructures();
```

I also have a list of Strings:

```
List<String> myList = getStrings();
```

I need to filter the first list (`structures`) so that it only contains elements, that in their `fields` array contain any of the Strings present on `myList`.

I thought about writing a for loops, something like:

```
List<MyStructure> outcomeStructures = new ArrayList<>(); 

for (MyStructure mystructure : structures) {
    for (String temp : mystructure.getFields()) {
        if (myList.contains(temp) {
            outcomeStructures.add(mystructure);
        }
    }
}
```

but maybe there's a better way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that working?

Comment: have a look into the Java streaming capabilities. I believe this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the better performance you can convert the `List<String> myList = getStrings();` to `Set<String> mySet` since [HashSet time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247854/hashset-contains-performance) for `contains` is `O(1)` always. Then use:

```
List<MyStructure> outcomeStructures = structures.stream()
        .filter(st -> Arrays.stream(st.getFields()).anyMatch(mySet::contains))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think there's some problem, the collect function is not visible here, perhaps I should call it on something else than the result of anyMatch, that returns boolean?

Comment: @randomuser1 Did you make sure the brackets put in the code are appropriately matched? Try out the current code, I can confirm it compiles successfully.