# Find widest subarray with given sum (array slicing)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I stumbled recently on a modified [maximum sum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), here we know the sum (let's say it's `S=2`) but we need to find a longest slice of array which produces this exact sum (longest means must have biggest number of elements)

So for input array

```
A = [1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

We find 2 slices:
`A(0:4)` because `sum(1,0,-1,1,1)` is `2`
and `A(3:4)` because `sum(1,1)` is also `2`

But the `A(0:4)` subarray is the longest thus it's length `5` is the answer here..

Most of the solution's I found where not O(n) because they used 2 loops instead of a one or some packages for collections. Is this variant of problem even possible to solve with O(n) complexity?

I'm mostly interested in a solution written in Java, but don't know which algorithm to model.

```
assert solution(new int[] { 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 }, 2) == 5;
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in O(n) as well:

First, create an auxilary array that sums each prefix of the array:

```
sums[i] = arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[i]
```

The above can be computed in `O(n)` time.

Next, create a hash map `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`, where the key is representing a prefix sum, and the value is a list of indices with this prefix sum. Pseudo code:

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
   List<Integer> l = map.get(sums[i]);
   if (l == null) { 
       l = new ArrayList<>();
       map.put(sums[i],l);
   }
   l.add(i);
}
```

Now, iterate the sums array, and for each element `x`, check if the map contains a key `k` such that `x-k == S`.

This is done by checking if it has a key `k = S-x`, which is O(1) in  a hash map.

If there is such a key, then get the last index in the values list, which is also done in `O(1)`, and take it as a candidate match.

Pseudo code:

```
int currentMaxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) { 
   int k = S-sums[i];
   List<Integer> l = map.get(k);
   if (l == null) continue;
   int width = Math.abs(l.getLast() -  i);
   if (width > currentMaxLength) currentMaxLength = width;
}
return currentMaxLength;
```

The idea is, if you have multiple matches for some `x1,x2` such that `x2-x1 = S`, and where `x1,x2` are prefix sums, the candidates for longest subarray are the first place where `x1` appears, and the last place where `x2` appears.

For `x1`, this is the element which `i` refers to in the main loop, and it is always regarded as a candidate.

For `x2`, you will always check the last occurance of `x2`, and thus it's correct.

**Quicknote**: The actual code also needs to regard `sums[-1] = 0`.

---

**Java code:**

```
public static int solution(int[] arr, int S) { 
    int[] sums = new int[arr.length+1];
    int sum = 0;
    //generate the sums array:
    sums[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) sums[i+1] = sum = sum+arr[i];
    //generate map:
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
       List<Integer> l = map.get(sums[i]);
       if (l == null) { 
           l = new ArrayList<>();
           map.put(sums[i],l);
       }
       l.add(i);
    }
    //find longest:
    int currentMaxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) { 
       int k = S - sums[i];
       List<Integer> l = map.get(k);
       if (l == null) continue;
       int width = Math.abs(l.get(l.size()-1) -  i);
       if (width > currentMaxLength) currentMaxLength = width;
    }
    return currentMaxLength;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solution(new int[] { 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 }, 2));
}
```

Comment: HashMap's get and put operations are amortized O(1). The complexity here is O(2n * 1) in the best scenario, and in the worst is O(2 * (n^2)). Because we can expect linear time in most of the scenarios, I'd like to accept this answer. - reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity

Comment: @oski86 The complexity is `O(n)` average case, and indeed `O(n^2)` worst case. Note that if the array contains for example small values, , you could use a bitset instead, at the expanse of `O(S)` memory (where S is the difference between maximal prefix sum and minimal prefix sum). Another alternative is a `TreeMap`, that will make the algorithm run in O(nlogn) all cases.

Answer (score -1):

Think of something like this:

If you have a array T[A:D] and the maximum sub array of T[A:D] is T[B:C], then you get a next element T[E], you therefore need the maximum sub array of [A:E], this sub array MUST BE either the old T[B:C], or the T[B:E].