# Should you check for a duplicate before inserting into a set

Tags: java, performance, set, big-o

I am learning to use sets. My question is : Sets do not contain duplicates. When we try to insert duplicates, it does not throw any error and automatically removes duplicates. Is it a good practice to check each value before inserting into set whether it exists or not? Or is it OK to do something like the below code? I think Java would be internally doing the check using `.contains(value)` . What do you think?

What would be the Big O complexity in both the cases considering there are *n* elements going into the set?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();

         mySet.add(10);
         mySet.add(20);
         mySet.add(30);
         mySet.add(40);
         mySet.add(50);
         mySet.add(50);
         mySet.add(50);
         mySet.add(50);
         mySet.add(50);
         mySet.add(50);

         System.out.println("Contents of the Hash Set :"+mySet);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because a `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, your answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4553642/4490686

Comment: It doesn't do a `contains` instead it just won't add an element which is already there, i.e. it doesn't add any overhead to do this.

Comment: Just FYI you can't change Big Oh complexity by adding another operation with the same complexity as the one that is already applied. What I mean, is that both `for(int x: set) { set.add(x); }` and `for(int x:set) { set.contains(x); set.add(x); }` have the same Big Oh complexity, as long as `add` and `contains` have the same complexity. Because O(C*n) == O(n), for any constant number C.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your set. Do you want to find out if sth. is duplicated, then such a check would be necessary, if you only want to remove doublettes, then the set already does everything you want.

Comment: @Aron_dc: since `add` returns a `boolean` telling you whether the element has been added or was a duplicate, there is *never* any reason to check before adding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashMap get/put complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity)

Comment: @Holger. I have run into cases where you do need to check. In particular, w.r.t. memory use and caching. A million nodes each holding a ("readonly") reference to a different but equivalent copy of something is substantially different in practice than every node holding a reference to the same copy. So you check if the copy is in the (Weak)HashSet, and if so, discard it in favor of the one already there in the set. A little convoluted, but a counterexample none the less.

Comment: @TLW: if you are going to remove the element, if it exists, invoking `contains` before `remove` is the same kind of anti-pattern. Just invoke only `remove` and check the `boolean` result…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is easily answered by simply reading the documentation as the accepted answer proves!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29):

> `public boolean add(E e)`
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). *If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.*

So the `add()` method already returns you a true or a false. So you don't need to do the additional check.

Answer (score 10):

Compare with [the API documentation of `Set.add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))

The `add` method checks if the element is already in the `Set`. If the element is already present, then the new element is not added, and the `Set` remains unchanged. In most situations, you don't need to check anything.

The complexity of the method depends of the concrete implementation of Set that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Its ok not to check. This is the main advantage over Sets of Lists, as they will automatically filter out duplicates.

HashSet has constant time performance (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets

Comment: @YassinHajaj - have linked to APIi and provided the relevant section.

Answer (score 2):

The add function returns a boolean which you can check to determine if the item was already in the Set. This is of course based on your needs and isn't a best practice. Its good to know that it will not remove an item that is already there so it can't be depended on to update the existing value with new information if you are defining equals based on surrogate keys from your database. This is opposite the way Maps work as a map will return any existing value and replace it with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Here are answers to your questions:

> When we try to insert duplicates, it does not throw any error and
>   automatically removes duplicates.

Your understanding is not correct. The call to `Set.add()` will not add a new item if it is already in the set; this statement applies to all implementations of `Set`, including `HashSet` and `TreeSet`.

> Is it a good practice to check each value before inserting into set
>   whether it exists or not? or is it okay to do something like the below
>   code? I think java would be internally doing the check using
>   .contains(value) . What do you think?

Because your understanding was incorrect from the start, then you do not need to check each value before inserting into the set to see if it already exists. Yes, internally, it is doing something like `contains()`.

> What would be the Big Oh complexity in both the cases considering
>   there are "n" elements going into the set?

For HashSet, the time complexity is `O(1)` for each `add()`. For `TreeSet()` -- which you didn't use -- the time complexity is `O(lg N)` for each `add()`.

Comment: A HashSet can have a complexity of `O(n)` if the hashing algorithm is not optimal