# Finding next occurance for each element in array in O(n)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Suppose I have an array like this : `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]`

I want to get an output like 1 ==> 6 ( For element 1(0<sup>th</sup> index the match is found at index 6)

This means for 0<sup>th</sup> element the next match is found at 6th index.

If the input is `[4,6,4,6]` the output is 4 ==> 2 and 6 ==> 3

Since first match for 4 is found at index 2( which is four) and first match for six(2<sup>nd</sup> element) is found at 3<sup>rd</sup> index

If the time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) the solution is pretty straight forward. I have tried to find the next greatest element with this code in O(n) using stack. But I couldn't find a way to do the same for next equal element.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class NextGreatestElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inp = {1,4,6,2,39};
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(inp[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < inp.length; i++) {
            int element = inp[i];
            if (element > stack.peek()) {
                System.out.println(stack.peek() + " ==> " + element);
                stack.pop();
                while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(stack.pop() + " ==> " + element);
                }
                stack.push(element);
            } else if (element < stack.peek()) {
                stack.push(element);
            }
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) System.out.println(stack.pop() + " ==> " + (-1));
    }
}
```

Even Algorithm is enough. I don't need the code.

Comment: What does `next greatest element` mean?

Comment: For this input [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1] the next greatest elements are for 1 it is 2 and 2 it is 3 and so on and for six nothing is there

Comment: The best complexity you can achieve is of O(nlogn) using Quick sort to sort the array and then traversing through it to find the the element who has no greater successor in the array.

Comment: So, basically you want the smallest value and the biggest value with O(n) ? What do you expect when ou have [ 1, 2, 3, 48, 5, 6, 1]

Comment: @Asew I don't want smallest and biggest values I want next equal element

Comment: cannot understand your question properly, do you need to find the greatest number in an array?

Comment: I struggle to understand your question...

Comment: What do you want when you have [ 1, 2, 3, 48, 5, 6, 1], and [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 48]

Comment: For [1,2,3,48,5,6,1] it is 6 and for next it is 3

Comment: "next equal element to all elements" doesn't mean anything to me

Comment: @bharath seriously, can't understand your question. please provide a set of input and outputs

Comment: On the title you are asking for the "next equal element", on the body you are asking for the "the index of the element who has no greater successor in the array" and later on the body you are asking for "the next greatest element". Stick to one!

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Some one edited my question sorry for that I will edit it right now

Comment: Do you want the index of the last element which has no direct successor greater than him ? [1,2,3,1] => 3, [1,50,21,67] =>50

Comment: Guys I've edited the question now it is very clear..Sorry for the previous one

Comment: I am even more confused.. In the end you want the last index of each unique element ?

Comment: Not the last index of each unique element....The next occurance of current element is what I asked

Comment: Ah ! Finally I understood.

Comment: Thank god.. I'm sorry you haven't understood it before

Comment: I still can't undestand.. it is me or what?

Comment: Seems I got it right then. @bharath, please, add a full sample of input and a corresponding output

Comment: let's see if I'm correct: for each element which appears more than once, you want the indexes of all the repeated values

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini bro listen... I have an array like this [2,4,4,6,46,4,2]...You can see that some elements occured more than once in the array. For such type of elements I want to find the next occurance. In this example 4 has occured several times. I want to find the next occurance of each 4. So for first 4(1st index ) it is 2 (2nd index) and for next 4(second index) it is 5(5th index)

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini For you I hope that the question is clear now

Comment: now I got it, your question should have been: "for each element appearing more than once, I want the indexes of all the repeated values"

Comment: No man I don't want the index of all repeated values. I just want the index of next repeated one :/

Comment: having a list like this : `1,2,1,3,1,3, 5,1` the result would be : `1 = 2, 1 = 4, 3 = 5, 1 = 7`?

Comment: Eugene exactly !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to implement it with a stack in `O(n)`. You can take a `HashMap` and iterate from right to left saving the last occurrence of a number. It will give you `O(n)` average-case time complexity:

```
int[] inp = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3};
Map<Integer, Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = inp.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int cur = inp[i];
    int next = -1;
    if (h.containsKey(cur)) {
        next = h.get(cur);
    }   
    h.put(cur, i);
    result.add(next);
}

for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Number " + inp[i] + " next occurence at index " + result.get(inp.length - i - 1));
}
```

Runnable version: http://ideone.com/i6Cx09

Comment: @bharath, take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not mistaken if you want the element or get the element that occurs in array  more than onece. You can do this.

This solution will be **nlogn**

1. Sort the array (ascending)
2. loop array then compare
3. if a[i] == a[i+1] then list.add(a[i]);

something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ets3f.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use a hashmap or hashtable

traverse from right to left, for the first occurrence input the value into the collection

```
collection_object.put(inp[i], ""+i)
```

when you encounter next time just change the value like

```
value = collection_object.get(inp[i])
v = value.split("==>")
value = v[0] + "==>" + i
collection_object.put(inp[i], value)
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer

Comment: HashMap<int, String> collection_object = new HashMap<int, String> (); collection_object is a hashmap, where while iterating through the input array , when you encounter an element for the first time then just input the element with its index as key, value respectively, for the next time when you encounter the same element . use the second code

Comment: omg finally i understood your question after reading all the comments, please be specify when you ask the question.

Comment: Its not my fault... Someone edited my question and I thought its grammar correction but it has changed entire meaning

Comment: @bharath, Do you understand my answer?

Comment: Dale your answer is clear than this but I think h.containsKey might produce O(n) resulting in O(n^2) over all

Comment: @bharath, HashMap has `O(1)` find-key operation in average-case. The worst-case time could be worse, but that's not the case: we have integers as keys and one of the most tested implementations of a hash table.