# What is the time complexity of put() and get() operation in Guava ListMultimap?

Tags: java, time-complexity, guava, multimap

What is the `time complexity` of `put()` and `get()` in [Guava ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) or [Guava ArrayListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) ?

I have read the below  Guava Documentation, However, the time complexity of these operations is not mentioned.

[ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)

[ArrayListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html)

Is the time complexity same as that of Hashmap (`O(1)` for both `put()` and `get()`)?

Comment: Did you examine the source for those classes to see what they do?

Comment: The `ArrayListMultimap` just uses an `ArrayList` internally.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I read about it's super interface Multimap [link](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). But nothing has been mentioned about time complexity of methods in the super interface.

Comment: @Ben Does that mean it's an O(n) operation if it is using ArrayList? So, If I want O(1) time complexity in put() and get() operation, should I use HashMultimap [link](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described, though a bit indirectly, on guava's general [documentation for multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap). Specifically, in the "Implementations" section, it says that for ArrayListMultimap, the keys behave as HashMap, and the values behave as ArrayList.

Thus, the get and put are both O(1) (with the [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity) about that claim that accompany HashMap). For get, it's just an O(1) operation that gets the ArrayList; for put, it's that same O(1) get, and then another O(1) put (amortized, as ArrayList additions always are).