# Why is this method's time complexity 2*O(n log n) + O(m log m)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The code below tries to check if all the words in `searchWords` appear in `newsPaperWords`. Both lists can contain duplicates. If a word appears n times in `searchWords`, it'll have to appear at least n times in `newsPaperWords` for the method to return true. I thought that the time complexity was `2*O(n) + O(m)` but the interviewer told me that it is `2*O(n log n) + O(m log m)`.

```
/**
 * @param searchWords The words we're looking for. Can contain duplicates
 * @param newsPaperWords  The list to look into
 */
public boolean wordMatch(List<String> searchWords, List<String> newsPaperWords) {
    Map<String, Integer> searchWordCount = getWordCountMap(searchWords);
    Map<String, Integer> newspaperWordCount = getWordCountMap(newsPaperWords);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> searchEntry : searchWordCount.entrySet()) {
        Integer occurrencesInNewspaper = newspaperWordCount.get(searchEntry.getKey());
        if (occurrencesInNewspaper == null || occurrencesInNewspaper < searchEntry.getValue()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private Map<String, Integer> getWordCountMap(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : words) {
        Integer occurrencesThisWord = result.get(word);
        if (occurrencesThisWord == null) {
            result.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            result.put(word, occurrencesThisWord + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As I see it, the time complexity of the method is `2*O(n) + O(m)` (being n the number of elements in `searchWords` and m the number of elements in `newsPaperWords`):

- The method `getWordCountMap()` has a complexity of `O(n)`, being n the number of elements in the given list. The method loops the list once, and assuming that the calls to `result.get(word)` and `result.put()` are `O(1)`.
- Then, the iteration over `searchWordCount.entrySet()` is, worst-case, `O(n)`, assuming, again, that calls to `Hashmap.get()` are `O(1)`.

So, simply adding, `O(n) + O(m)` to build the two maps plus `O(n)` for the last look.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553642/9647022), taking `O(n)` as worst-case complexity for `HashMap.get()`, I could understand that the complexity of `getWordCountMap()` goes up to `O(n*2n)` and the final loop to `O(n*n)`, which would give a total complexity of `O(n*2n) + O(m*2m) + O(n*n)`.

But how is it `2*O(n log n) + O(m log m)`?

Comment: "*but the interviewer told me that it is `2*O(n log n) + O(m log m)`*" - If anything, this would collapse to `O(n log n + m log m)`.

Comment: Seems you did not read that answer enough, as it states that In JDK 8 worst case is log n for HashMap.get()

Comment: @juvian The documentation for [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-), [JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#) and [JDK 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) state that: "*This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.*".

Comment: @Turing85 and without assuming anything, its log n

Comment: @juvian huh... that's funny. Just after reading karol-dowbecki's answer was I reminded of this fact. Why is this not in the documentation?

Comment: @juvian: I think it is only reasonable to assume that the hash function will adequately do its job. If we are going to get Log n from HashMap too, then we might as well use a self-balancing m-way tree.

Comment: @displayName I believe its reasonable, but seems his interviewer doesn´t

Comment: @juvian: Agreed. Probably the interviewer is trying to figure out if the candidate knows what happens in an extreme situation.

Comment: @displayName In this case, I would tend to disagree. This behaviour is not documented in the API, and not everyone reads JEPs regularly.

Comment: @Turing85: I agree with you too. The interviewer, though, is free to ask such a question. An interview is a bi-direction process. If the interviewee finds the interviewer's questions disinteresting, then the candidate can/should reject the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [JEP 180: Handle Frequent HashMap Collisions with Balanced Trees](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180) the worst case for `HashMap.get()` operation will be `O(log n)`. To quote the JEP 180:

> The principal idea is that once the number of items in a hash bucket grows beyond a certain threshold, that bucket will switch from using a linked list of entries to a balanced tree. In the case of high hash collisions, this will improve worst-case performance from O(n) to O(log n).

This would make `getWordCountMap()` method `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity you have deduced is correct assuming the hashmap is using a proper hash function. This algorithm looks like *O(m + n)* to me.

---

I guess that your interviewer described the complexity of another approach to solving this problem which is more time-consuming but ends up taking less space.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. If the complexity that I have deduced is correct, why do you say is `O(m + n)`, while I got `O(m + 2*n)`?

Comment: @antonro: I thought it was obvious. Constants are not important in Big-O calculations. We only try to find the raw rate of growth by means of Big-O, not an exact rate of growth.

Comment: Ah ok, understood. Thanks.