# How to find all odd occurring elements in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find all the elements which occur an odd number of times in an array. I worked out a little bit, but my code is only returning the correct answer if there is only one number which occurs odd number of times. If there are two or more odd occurring numbers than I am not able to process it. What I understand is that if we do bit-wise XOR of elements than we get one odd occurring element. How can I improve it for multiple numbers?

Below is my code:

```
public class OddOccur {
    public int oddoccurence(int[] arr, int size) {
        int res = 0;
        int[] fin = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            res = res ^ arr[i];

        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = { 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };

        int n = arr.length;
        OddOccur obj = new OddOccur();

        System.out.println("odd occuring element is:"
                + obj.oddoccurence(arr, n));
    }
}
```

Need help to solve this issue!

Comment: How is this: res = res ^ arr[i]; going to help you figure out the odd numbers? Think about the properties of an even number...

Comment: I read that to find one odd number u just need to do bitwise XOR of all the numbers.I want to know that if we can modify this property to find all the odd number

Comment: would a `Map<Integer, Integer>` make the problem easier?

Comment: If I run the above program with only one number which occurs odd number of times in an array it returns correct answer

Comment: @pedromss I want to find number which occurs odd number of time in an array, not just an odd number

Comment: @Kent I think Hashmap is one of the ways to do it but I don't know how to use it get the answer.Can you provide the way?

Comment: @user2916886 when I was writing my answer, I saw John's post, he was faster! :D

Comment: Can you check if (i & 1) == 1 then it occured in an odd position or (arr[i] & 1) == 1 if you want to check if the numberis odd?

Comment: I don't think your algorithm of XOR works. Imagine this input array { 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2 }. The result 0^2=2, 2^5=X, X^5=2, 2^2=0, 0^3=3, 3^2=Y. You will return Y, whatever Y is and it is not 2.

Answer (score 5):

```
public int oddoccurence(int[] arr, int size);
```

First, there can be multiple numbers that occur an odd number of times. There's no way to write this function and make it work if it only returns a single `int`. You'll need a function which can return multiple numbers.

```
public int[] oddOccurrences(int[] array);
```

Second, don't try to be clever. Using XOR is "clever". You're not going to find a simple solution using XOR. It'll be some convoluted, complicated mess. Keep it simple:

1. Count the number of times each number appears.
2. Then find all the odd counts.

Example pseudo-code:

```
// Map from numbers to counts. Assume the counts start at 0.
Map<Integer, Integer> counts;

for (number in array) {
    counts[number] += 1
}

// List of numbers that occur an odd number of items.
List<Integer> oddNumbers;

for (number, count in counts) {
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        oddNumbers.add(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for explanation but I am having trouble in converting the above pseudo-code into a program.Can you help?

Comment: @user2916886 What specifically do you need help with? Which part is giving you trouble? Do you understand what it does conceptually?

Comment: I understand that with hashmap there is a mapping for each element of array and number of times that element occurs in array. what I am not able to translate into code is the 1st for loop(complete) and the 2nd for loop condition

Comment: @user2916886 Perhaps you can post a new question about how to translate the pseudo-code into actual Java. The comment area is not really suited for this. (Also, I have to step out for a while and won't be able to help you right now.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an old post.. but here my answer.

In my opinion is not necessary to count the occurrences of a number to determine if it's odd or not. Let's use a data structure like a `Set` and just add to it the item if is still not prenent or remove it if already there.

Something like this:

```
public int solution(int[] A){

    Set<Integer> unpaired = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
        if (unpaired.contains(A[i])){
            unpaired.remove(new Integer(A[i]));
        }else{
            unpaired.add(A[i]);
        }
    }


    // all printed out values are odd
    for (Integer res : unpaired){
        System.out.println(res);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution scored 100% on codility. What we do is simply initialize a HashMap. The lookup time for a HashMap is O(1) constant time, see [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469795/why-hashmap-lookup-is-o1-i-e-constant-time). Since we loop through the entire array only once, we end up with O(N) time, where N is the length of the array.

If an element already exists in the HashMap, then we can remove it since we have found its corresponding pair. By the end of this, we should end up with a HashMap with only a single  pair. Simply output this number and you are done.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int key;
        Map<Integer, Integer> unpaired = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            key  = A[i];
            Integer value = unpaired.get(key);
            if (value != null){
                unpaired.remove(key); // Remove by key
            }
            else{
                unpaired.put(key,0);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : unpaired.entrySet())
        {
            key =  entry.getKey();
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This score 100 % .

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i = i+2){
        if(i == A.length-1)
        return A[i];

        if (A[i]!=A[i+1])
        return A[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to keep track of how many times you've seen each integer, only whether you've seen it an odd number of times. So start with your data structure (map, hash table, dictionary, whatever) being empty, which correctly reflects the state that you have seen no numbers an odd number of times. Now for each number x in the array, if x is in the map then remove it (now you've seen it an even number of times) otherwise add it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using HashMap:

```
 public int solution(int[] A) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        HashSet<Integer> val = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        if (map.get(A[i]) == null) {
            map.put(A[i], 1);
        } else map.put(A[i], map.get(A[i])+1);

        if (map.get(A[i])%2 == 1) 
            val.add(A[i]);
            else val.remove(A[i]);
        }

        Iterator<Integer> itr = val.iterator();  
        return itr.next();  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use a `Map` to store the number of occurrences is the right method to solve this problem，but if the different numbers is too many it need more memory，use `BitMap` can also realize and need less memory.

```
public static List<Integer> oddNumbers(int[] array, int size) {
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            bitSet.flip(array[i]);
        }

        List<Integer> resp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.length(); i++) {
            if (bitSet.get(i)) {
                resp.add(i);
            }
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

The test case is:

```
@Test
public void test_oddNumbers() throws Exception {
    int[] arr = {2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9};
    List<Integer> resp = oddNumbers(arr, arr.length);
    assertTrue(resp.size() == 6);
    assertTrue(resp.containsAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//This solution scored 100% on codility.

import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8

    Arrays.sort(A);

    int length = A.length;

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (j < length && A[i] == A[j]) {
            i++;
            j = j + 2;
        } else {
            return A[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty simple, just use bitwise xor on all the elements of the array. The reason is that only one element is unpaired.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static int Odd(int[] a) {
        int unpaired;
        unpaired = a[0];

        for(int i = 1; i< a.length; i++){
            unpaired = unpaired ^ a[i]; // xor
        }

        return unpaired;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Program in kotlin

```
fun oddOccurrencesInArray(array: IntArray) {
   
    var count = 0
    var arrayList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    array.sort() //sort the array
    var element = array[0]
    for (j in 1 until array.size) {
        if (element == array[j]) {
            count++
        } else {
            if (count == 0)
                arrayList.add(array[j-1])
            count = 0
            element=array[j]
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        arrayList.add(array[array.size-1])
    println("Given array: ${array.contentToString()} missing:${arrayList.toString()}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This scored 100% in Codility using a **Set** object and simply adding if `!exist` or removing if `exists`.

```
public int solution(int[] A) 
{
    Set<Integer> oddSet = new HashSet<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if(!oddSet.contains(A[i]))
        {
            oddSet.add(A[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            oddSet.remove(A[i]);
        }
    }
    /* Based on the pre-conditions, we are sure that only one 
       remains here that is unique. So we just return that. */
    return oddSet.iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% solution in C# using Linq.  It's nice to see that Linq is fast enough.

```
  public static int solutionOddOccurrencesInArrayLinq(int[] A)
    {
        if (A.Length == 0)
            return 0;

         var result = A
            .GroupBy(e => e)
            .Where(g => g.Count() % 2 == 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);

        return result.FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution gave me 100% pass on codility:

```
  public int solution(int[] A) {

        if (A.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length ; i++) {
            // using XOR function 1. XOR of number with itself = 1 and XOR number with 0 = number itself
            num = num ^ A[i];
        }


        return num;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class GetOddOccurenceInArray {
    
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getOddOccurence(int arr[]){
        
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(); 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap();

        for(int num : arr){
            if(hmap.get(num) == null){
                hmap.put(num, count+1); 
            }
            else
                hmap.put(num, hmap.get(num)+1);
        }
          
        for (Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hmap.entrySet()) { 
            if(entry.getValue()%2==1){
                //System.out.println("number is "+entry.getKey());               
                result.add(entry.getKey());
            }

        }

        return result;      
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = {1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8};
        ArrayList<Integer> occurred = getOddOccurence(arr);
        System.out.println("numbers occurred odd times : "+ occurred.toString());   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this code snippet will work better than the one mentioned in the question and why.

Comment: It will return the list of all the numbers which had odd occurrences in the array for instance the arr[] which i mentioned in the above program will produce the following output :    numbers occurred odd times : [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]