# Element's equality check from list of object

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a `List` of `Employee` object.

```
class Employee{  
  private int empId;  
  private String name;  
}
```

Now I have

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

How can I find, if my list contains an employee named "ABC"??
`empList.contains("ABC");` wont work...

Should I put it in `Map`?? Which one is more efficient??

Just wanted to mention that I get my Employee object from database....

Comment: How could an `Employee` ever equal a `String`?

Comment: You are not declaring type for `empId` and `name`. May be you want `private int empId;` and `private String name;`

Comment: @afzalex - thanks... a typo.. .actually I have made a scenario to just simulate my problem

Comment: Just wanted to let you all know, that I get my Employee object from the database, in that case, I wont be able to create new Employee object from `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Map<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ABC", new Employee("ABC"));
map.put("John", new Employee("John"));
```

and then check

```
map.containsKey("ABC")
```

**Should I put it in Map?? Which one is more efficient??**

Because `contains()` method of list, calls `indexOf`, which needs to iterate over all elements
like this

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Where as map no need to iterate over all elements

Comment: Don't over ride equals to check contains ... rather add a new method to check if it contains. override equals when it needs to do equality check in a different way. What wait where did you get map from ?

Comment: Should I put it in Map?? Which one is more efficient?? posted by OP

Answer (score 1):

Override equals. You can then use List.contains

```
class Employee {  
    private empId;  
    private name;
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Employee && ((Employee)o).empId == empId && ((Employee)o).name = name);
    }
}
```

```
List l = ...;
Employee e = new Employee(...);
l.add(e);
l.contains(e);
```

Comment: ControlAltDel, `l.contains(e)` will return true even if you not have overriden that `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Only if the Employee object is the same object. Using equals lets you match on the actual values

Comment: I was considering your example.

Comment: How this answer is right. Look at the question, OP has editted it. @brso05. `contains(e)` will not return true if User create new object of `Employee` with same id and name.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the  `Employee` objects and not `String` in your list , i think it is impossible to search without looping through all list objects

```
for (Employee employee : empList) {
      if (employee.getName().equals(searchString))
        System.out.println("Found");
    }
```

*Note: Your Employee class should give access to name field either through getter method or change it to public*

---

There are other alternatives, but it depends on your requirements and tradeoff's between speed, space, readability, resources etc

One thing i can think of is `HashMap`, which has [constant time lookup in average case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469795/why-hashmap-lookup-is-o1-i-e-constant-time)

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
hm.put(1, "Tom");
System.out.println(hm.containsValue("Tom"));
```

Now,

> Should I put it in Map?? Which one is more efficient??

Instead of coding and analyzing,  [Know Thy Complexities](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) beforehand !

Comment: I had tried the same way using iterator... but I was thinking, if there is better way to do it. FYI - I have getter setter...

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, if you wanted to determine whether the employee list contains an employee named "ABC", you could do this:

```
boolean containsABC = empList.stream().anyMatch(emp -> emp.getName().equals("ABC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can use. 
I am considering that you want list to return true when `empId` and `name` of the `Employee` matches.
I also prefer to use Constructor in your code(Just recommendation).
The below code will run as you are wanting it to be.

```
class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String name;

    // below overriden function will return true if it found Employee with 
    // same ID and name
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Employee             //Checking instace of obj
            && ((Employee)obj).empId == empId       //Checking empId
            && ((Employee)obj).name.equals(name));  //Checking name
    }

    // Used constructor to create Employee
    Employee(int id, String nm) {
        empId = id;
        name = nm;
    }

}
```

Here is an example run :

```
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add(new Employee(1, "ME");
System.out.println(l.contains(new Employee(1, "ME")));  //print true
```

I would also like to acknowledge you that you should also override `hashCode()` when you decides to override `equals(...)` method according to **Design Pattern**.