# Why lookup is always constant time and not O(n)

Tags: javascript, computer-science, lookup

I'm using JavaScript, but I assume this is relevant for many computer languages.

Why lookup in `obj`(`Object`) in the following case is `O(1)`? Isn't it should be `O(n)`? Can anyone explain it to me please, like provide an actual, low-level explanation why this isn't `O(n)`?

```
let arr = ['m', 'k', 'b', 'z']
let obj = { 'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if ( obj[arr[i]] ) {
    return true
  }
}
```

The above time complexity is considered as `O(n)`, but hopefully you can see why this question is rising for me, because in order to find(for example) if `obj['b'] === arr[2]` (this is exactly what I do with the condition `if ( obj[arr[i]] )`), I will naturally think that it should go through all of the properties of `obj` and compare, but isn't that looping of it own kind, so to say overall it should be `O(n^2)`? Again, if not, please explain why, why it doesn't loop, but able to pick it immediately(`O(1)`).

Comment: Objects are hashes. It would be EXTREMELY bad if any property lookup was `O(n)` - it would more or less defeat the purpose of even using objects, since there would be such a significant loss of performance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469795/why-hashmap-lookup-is-o1-i-e-constant-time

Comment: if the language implementation creates a jump-table, you understand everything. For example see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table#Jump_table_example_in_C you must execute some arithmetic (for address calculation) and jump to needed code. This is O(1) time

Comment: Yes, I've got it, thank you.