# How to find if an entire list of values is represented in a one-dimensional array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to check if a one-dimensional array of objects contains specific values. I have an array of objects including people’s names and geographic locations. I am trying to check whether all continents are represented in the array.

I have tried to use a simple `for` loop to check through each element but it’s not working as intended.

My code:

```
function containsContinents(list, continents) {
  continents = ['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(list[i], continents) == -1) {
      return false;
    }
  } return true;
}
```

and the array of objects:

```
var list = [
  { firstName: 'Fatima', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Algeria', continent: 'Africa', age: 25, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Agustín', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Chile', continent: 'Americas', age: 37, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Laia', lastName: 'P.', country: 'Andorra', continent: 'Europe', age: 55, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Oliver', lastName: 'Q.', country: 'Australia', continent: 'Oceania', age: 65, language: 'PHP' },
];
```

Comment: What if a `continent` occurs that isn’t included in the `continents` array, e.g. `{ firstName: "Augustus", lastName: "Le Plongeon",`…`continent: "Mu",`…`}`, even if all others do? Valid or not?

Comment: Your algorithm checks to make sure that each continent is valid, but it makes no attempt to verify that all continents are seen in the list at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check if all continents are included at least once, you need to keep track of the continents you’ve found so far.

Since only the `continent` property is used, I’m going to simplify this array:

```js
const list = [
  { continent: "Africa" },
  { continent: "Americas" },
  { continent: "Asia" },
  { continent: "Europe" },
  { continent: "Oceania" },
];
```

You’re also resetting the `continents` parameter to an array in the question post, rather than use what has been passed.
The function call should look like `containsContinents(list, [ "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Oceania" ])` already, so setting the `continents` array inside the function is redundant.

Keeping track of found results is easy with [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
You can obtain a Set of all used continents and all expected continents by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
const usedContinents = new Set(list.map(({ continent }) => continent));
const expectedContinents = new Set(continents);
```

Now, you’re looking for a way to check if all expected continents occur in the used continents, but it’s not clear what is supposed to happen with used continents that are *not included* in the expected continents.

If your only criterion is *“for all continents of the expected continents, the continent exists in the used continents”*, then you have to check whether `expectedContinents` is a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of `usedContinents`.

If an additional criterion is *“the set of expected continents is the same as the set of used continents”* (i.e. no used continent exists that doesn’t exist in the expected continents), then simply checking if the set sizes are the same is sufficient.

This function checks the subset relation using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has):<sup>1</sup>

```js
const isSubset = (a, b) => Array.from(a).every((elem) => b.has(elem));
```

The full code now looks like this:

```js
const list = [
  { continent: "Africa" },
  { continent: "Americas" },
  { continent: "Asia" },
  { continent: "Europe" },
  { continent: "Oceania" }
];
const isSubset = (a, b) => Array.from(a).every((elem) => b.has(elem));
const allContinentsRepresented = (list, continents) => {
  const usedContinents = new Set(list.map(({ continent }) => continent));
  const expectedContinents = new Set(continents);

  return isSubset(expectedContinents, usedContinents);
  // Alternative:
  // return isSubset(expectedContinents, usedContinents) && expectedContinents.size === usedContinents.size;
};

console.log(allContinentsRepresented(list, [ "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Oceania" ]));
```

If you want to exclude all unexpected continents, include the additional `expectedContinents.size === usedContinents.size` check.
In that case, if the list contains an additional `{ continent: "Mu" }`, but the passed `continents` array doesn’t, the `allContinentsRepresented` function will return `false`.

<sup>1</sup>: The [New Set methods TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods) will allow a simple `a.isSubsetOf(b)` or `b.isSupersetOf(a)` in the future.

---

### [Runtime complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/4642212)

Others have suggested to check `continents.every((continent) => list.some((listItem) => listItem.continent === continent))`.
This has a quadratic runtime complexity (i.e. *O*(n²)), because the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) has to perform a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) through the array, but so does the `every`.
Since `some` is called *for each element*, the time complexity is multiplied: *O*(n · n).

The approach with `Set`s is approximately linear (i.e. *O*(n)), as Sets use [constant lookup time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15469795/4642212) internally (like [hash maps / hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)).
See also: [Javascript ES6 computational/time complexity of collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31091772/4642212).
The `every` call performs a linear pass through the array, but the lookup with `has` requires approximately constant time.

Essentially, this means that the Set approach is more efficient.

(Note that `Array.from`, the two `new Set` calls, and the `map` call all perform a linear pass, but these calls are not nested; they’re not performed *for every* element within *another* linear pass, so the runtime complexity isn’t affected by all these calls.)

Comment: Great answer. You are right about runtime complexity getting out of hand when using .every(item => list.some())

Answer (score 3):

This will check if all elements in you continent and list array match,It will return true if all your elements match.

```
   let continents = ['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
    var list = [
      { firstName: 'Fatima', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Algeria', continent: 'Africa', age: 25, language: 'JavaScript' },
      { firstName: 'Agustín', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Chile', continent: 'Americas', age: 37, language: 'C' },
      { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
      { firstName: 'Laia', lastName: 'P.', country: 'Andorra', continent: 'Europe', age: 55, language: 'Ruby' },
      { firstName: 'Oliver', lastName: 'Q.', country: 'Australia', continent: 'Oceania', age: 65, language: 'PHP' },
    ];
    
    const found = continents.every((r) => typeof list.find( (a) => a.continent === r) !== 'undefined')

    
    console.log('a',found);
```

Comment: I've update my answer, Check if it now fufills your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var list = [
  {
    firstName: 'Fatima',
    lastName: 'A.',
    country: 'Algeria',
    continent: 'Africa',
    age: 25,
    language: 'JavaScript',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Agustín',
    lastName: 'M.',
    country: 'Chile',
    continent: 'Americas',
    age: 37,
    language: 'C',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jing',
    lastName: 'X.',
    country: 'China',
    continent: 'Asia',
    age: 39,
    language: 'Ruby',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Laia',
    lastName: 'P.',
    country: 'Andorra',
    continent: 'Europe',
    age: 55,
    language: 'Ruby',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Oliver',
    lastName: 'Q.',
    country: 'Australia',
    continent: 'Oceania',
    age: 65,
    language: 'PHP',
  },
];

const continents = ['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];

const allContinentsAreThere = continents.every((continent) =>
  list.some((listItem) => listItem.continent === continent)
);

console.log(allContinentsAreThere);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check all the continents is resent in the list

Logic

- Loop through `continents`
- Check if a node is present in list having continent from `continents` array.
- If any node is not present, set the bool to false.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var list = [
  { firstName: 'Fatima', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Algeria', continent: 'Africa', age: 25, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Agustín', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Chile', continent: 'Americas', age: 37, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Laia', lastName: 'P.', country: 'Andorra', continent: 'Europe', age: 55, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Oliver', lastName: 'Q.', country: 'Australia', continent: 'Oceania', age: 65, language: 'PHP' },
];

const continents = ['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];

function containsContinents(list, continents) {
  let isAllContinentExist = true;
  continents.forEach((continent) => {
    isAllContinentExist = isAllContinentExist && list.find((node) => node.continent === continent) !== undefined;
  });
  return isAllContinentExist;
}
console.log(containsContinents(list, continents));
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon updated the answer, please check and revet the downvote is issue resolved.