# Difference between string arrays in PHP

Tags: php

Given two arrays of strings, A and B.

B contains every element in A, and has one additional member, for example:

```
A = ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey]
B = ['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey']
```

I need to write a function to find the extra string in B using `O(n)`. Please help!

UPDATE: I know the difference can be achieved using PHP in-built function array_diff().

Comment: What do you mean by O(n)

Comment: Big-O notation For more details please refer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the built-in function `array_diff`:

```
$A = array('dog', 'cat', 'monkey');
$B = array('cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey');
$difference = array_diff($B, $A);
```

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67c405243726027ac5883f040d59b5926c828b43)

[Official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: I don't want built-in PHP function. I did mention using big-O notation.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This is the most efficient solution since built-in PHP functions are heavily tested and optimized.

Comment: @Joren clearly it's a learning exercise.  `array_diff` isn't something that is available out of the box across all languages - people these days use existing code too readily without understanding the implementation.  Yes, using the internal functionality will be faster and best-practice but asking *how* it works and what the alternatives are surely can't be a bad thing!

Comment: Here is the C implementation used by PHP: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/array.c#3441

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help you

```
$A = array('dog', 'cat', 'monkey');
$B = array('cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey');

function arrayDiff($A, $B) {
    $out = array();
    foreach($B as $b) $out[$b] = 1;
    foreach($A as $a) unset($out[$a]);
    return array_keys($out);
}

print_r(arrayDiff($A, $B));
```

If you do not want to use `array_keys()` change function as following

```
function arrayDiff($A, $B) {
    $res = $out = array();
    foreach($A as $a) $out[$a] = 1;
    foreach($B as $b) if(!isset($out[$b])) $res[] = $b;
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Technically this has efficiency O(n+m)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Lookup through a hash table is O(1).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1