# Is a lookup in a hash table O(1)?

Tags: complexity-theory

If a hash table holds N distinct items, and is not overloaded, then the hashes for the N items must have have approximately lg(N) bits, otherwise too many items will get the same hash value.

But a hash table lookup is usually said to take O(1) time on average.

It's not possible to generate lg(N) bits in O(1) time, so the standard results for the complexity of hash tables are wrong.

What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: O(1) is just a expected :D

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1643 (linked what seems to be an identical question on that site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/27748)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can hash tables really be O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1)

Comment: @DavidRR It would be a shame to lose the accepted answer here. The accepted answer of the other question does not seem to me to be sound -- it asserts the impossible -- that one can have a fixed size hash function (reading a fixed number of bits of input) and yet preserve O(1) lookups as the number of entries in the table increases to infinity. The answer of R.Martinho Fernandes is exactly correct in my opinion, and I found it hugely helpful in my understanding of complexity theory.

Comment: @PaulHankin Answers to a closed question are never lost. It is just that new answers cannot be added to a closed question. That said, perhaps it would be fairer to say that your question and the one that I referenced are *related* rather than *duplicates*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is wrong with your reasoning is the use of conflicting definitions of "time".

When one says that lookup in a hash table takes O(1) time, one usually means that it takes O(1) *comparisons*, that is, the number of comparisons required to find an item is bounded above by a constant. Under this idea of "time", the actual time (as in the thing you would measure in seconds) used to compute the hash causes no variation.

Measuring time in comparisons is an approximation that, while it may not reflect reality in the same way that measuring it in seconds would, still provides useful information about the behaviour of the hash table.

This sort of thing is true for most asymptotic complexity descriptions of algorithms: people often use "time" with a very abstract meaning that isn't the informal meaning of "time", but more often than not is some variation of "number of operations" (with the kind of operation often left unstated, expected to be obvious, or clear from context).

Comment: Excellent answer. O(1) can be thought of as "the number of elements in population does not affect algorithm runtime".

Answer (score 0):

The analysis is based on the assumption that the hash function is fixed and not related to the actual number of elements stored in the table. Rather than saying that the hash function returns a lg N-bit value if there are N elements in the hash table, the analysis is based on a hash function that returns, say, a *k*-bit value, where *k* is independent of *N*. Typical value of *k* (such as 32 or 64) provide for a hash table far larger than anything you need in practice.

So in once sense, yes, a table holding N elements requires a hash function that returns O(lg n) bits; but in practice, a constant that is far larger than the anticipated maximum value of lg n is used.

Answer (score 0):

When we state the complexity of hash table insertion, we're not talking about some abstract concept of hash table insertion.  We're talking about a specific algorithm for hash table insertion or, more accurately, a class of algorithms that differ only in irrelevant details.

A "hash table insertion" algorithm that generates variable length hashes according to the number of elements in the table, and which therefore takes more time to hash when there are more elements, would be unusual.  Unless explicitly stated, that is not the kind of algorithm we're talking about when we give the complexity of "hash table insertion".

Now, a normal "hash table insertion" algorithm is specified for a type of computer called a [RAM (random access machine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), which is a type of computer that is like a normal computer in terms of time complexity.  This makes our statements of complexity *useful*. Unlike a normal computer, though, a RAM has no specified memory limit.  It is still assumed, however, that *address-sized numbers can be manipulated in constant time*, and this is a feature of real computers as well.

In a normal hash table implementation, the size of a hash is a bounded multiple of the computer's address size, and so you are just mistaken when you say "It's not possible to generate log(N) bits in O(1) time".  It *is* possible, and normal hashing algorithms take the same amount of time no matter how many elements are in the table.  (They do depend on the length of keys, though).

Comment: I think you're right (and can reasonably replace the RAM model with the word RAM model where cells have a fixed size that grows as log(N), which makes the model somewhat closer to a real computer). Just counting comparisons also makes a lot of sense though, and this neatly removes any consideration of weird computational models (which all have their quirks-- for example in the RAM model you can sort N things faster than O(N log N) time). Sedgwick measures hash table lookups by the number of comparisons, so I guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: The RAM model can not do a comparison sort faster than N log N.  It can do a radix sort in O(N), just like a real machine.  I think counting comparisons in a hash table algorithm makes no sense at all, except the "is there a real key match for the hash match" part.

Answer (score -1):

Hashtable search is O(1).
I think you are mixing insertion(which is O(n)) and search.

Comment: search in a hastable is *expected* O(1). But the worstcase is still O(n).