# How to search for anagrams in O(logN) time given an input from the user?

Tags: python, binary-search, anagram

Hi I've been thinking of how to implement this for days.

I'm trying to implement a programme that reads a dictionary into a list and sorts it in **O(N)** time.After that, I have to search for the anagrams in the list given an input from the user in **O(log N)** time.I can sort each word by letter and sort the list alphabetically in O(N).

Since I'm trying to search in O(logN) time, I tried to use binary search by sorting every letter in each word and using that as a key to identify the anagrams.
For example 'act' is the key for anagram group 'act,'cat','tac'.

```
arr=['act','cat','tac','bad','fad']
```

After sorting

```
[['act', 'act'], ['cat', 'act'], ['tac', 'act'], ['bad', 'abd'],  ['fad', 'adf']]
```

But binary search only finds ONE target so it will only return 'tac' for anagram group under 'act'.My binary search code:

```
def binarySearch(arr, lower, upper, target):
anagramList=[]
if upper >= lower:
    mid = lower + ((upper - lower) // 2)
    if areAnagrams(arr[mid][1],target):
        anagramList.append(arr[mid])
    elif arr[mid] > target:
        return binarySearch(arr, lower, mid - 1, target)
    else:
        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, upper, target)
return anagramList
```

I tried to group them like this

```
[['act','act','cat','tac'],['bad','abd'],['fad','daf]]
```

but it takes O(N^2) complexity which is larger than O(N)?Can anyone suggest how I should go about this?Thanks.

Edit:
For example, if the query string is alppe, the output will consist of the words appel, and apple.

Comment: You probably want to use a list, right? If not, you could always resort to a dictionary.

Comment: There's no partial matches allowed, right? You always need the full word? Can you supply some more inputs and expected outputs so we know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Megalng Well dictionary takes O(N) insert so worst case is O(N^2) so no

Comment: @Håken Lid Ok I've edited it

Comment: @SookLim How is the answer by HakenLid O(N^2)? Insert is O(N) and lookup is O(1). But maybe I am misunderstanding big-O notation.

Comment: Ya but by inserting every word into the dictionary it takes O(N^2) time.Say for i in range(len(list)) insert into dict?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary with the key being the word with letters sorted.

```
from collections import defaultdict
anagrams = defaultdict(list)

arr=['act','cat','tac','bad','fad']

for word in arr:
    anagrams[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)

def get_anagram(user_input):
    return anagrams[''.join(sorted(user_input))]
```

Example:

```
>>> get_anagram('tca')
['act', 'cat', 'tac']
```

Comment: Then the time complexity for reading and sorting the file wouldn't be O(N)?

Comment: @SookLim The Python wiki states that insert is O(1) (worst case O(N)) and getitem the same: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity with n being the size of the container. Multply that with the size of the input array and you achive worst case O(n*n), you are correct, but that is unlikely.

Comment: If `N` is the length of the input `arr`, building the lookup hashmap is `O(n)`. If individual words are within some upper bound (from the example in the question, that should not be an unreasonable assumption), then we can assert sorting keys also have a upper limit constant time.

Comment: @Megalng Sorry I meant worst case time complexity as O(N)

Comment: @MegaIng: Why would you multiply insert and getitem operation?

Comment: @HåkenLid Because you have to do a dict insert for every element of the input array. That is not quite correct with the multiplication, but I don't know how to do that correct. But it is not O(n^2), It could be something like O(n+log(n)) Or something like that. But most certainly it is O(n)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it's implemented, but I think we only need one get or insert operation. In any case, O(n) worst case performance for hash table is only a theoretical possibility. Typical case is O(1). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Counter from [collections](https://kite.com/python/docs/collections) module. The Counter class is not hashable so we will make it hashable dict from it.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict


class hashablecounter(Counter):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))


d = defaultdict(list)
arr=['act','cat','tac','bad','fad']

for a in arr:
    d[hashablecounter(a)].append(a)

s = 'cat'
print('Anagrams for ', s, ' are ', d[hashablecounter(s)])
```