# Time Complexity of getting value when key is very long

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, key-value

Let's assume that keys of dictionary are very long, and their length is around M where M is a very large number.

Then does it mean in terms of M, the time complexity of operations like

```
 x=dic[key]
 print(dic[key])
```

is O(M)?  not O(1)?

How does it work?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about string keys with `M` characters, yes, it *can* be `O(M)`, and on two counts:

1. Computing the hash code can take `O(M)` time.
2. If the hash code of the key passed in matches the hash code of a key in the table, then the implementation has to go on to compute whether they're equal (what `__eq__()` returns). If they are equal, that requires exactly `M+1` comparisons to determine (`M` for each character pair, and another compare at the start to verify that the (integer) string lengths are the same).

In rare cases it can be constant-time (independent of string length): those where the passed-in key *is* the same object as a key in the table. For example, in

```py
k = "a" * 10000000
d = {k : 1}
print(k in d)
```

Time it, and compare to when, e.g., adding this line before the end:

```
k = k[:-1] + "a"
```

The change builds another key *equal* to the original `k`, but is not the same object. So an internal pointer-equality test doesn't succeed, and a full-blown character-by-character comparison is needed.