# Why does casting an int to a bool give a warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, boolean, compiler-warnings

Shouldn't it be ok to use `static_cast` to convert int to bool as it converts reverse of implicit conversion but i still get a warning?

**Example:**

MSVC++ 8

```
bool bit = static_cast<bool>(100);
```

Comment: Even with `-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic`, g++ doesn't complain about this. What compiler are you using? Maybe post the precise code?

Comment: @Thomas With all those flags, I don't even get any warning from g++ (4.5.2) __without__ the cast (bool bit = 100;). Is that normal?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just because the conversion a => b is implicit doesn’t say anything about the viability of the reverse, b => a.

In your case, you shouldn’t cast at all. Just do the obvious thing: compare:

```
bool result = int_value != 0;
```

This is the only logically correct way of converting an `int` to `bool` and it makes the code much more readable (because it makes the assumptions explicit).

The same applies for the reverse, by the way. Converting implicitly from `bool` to `int` is just lazy. Make the mapping explicit:

```
int result = condition ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Define "correct", please. Do you mean, the only one permitted by your style guide?

Comment: I know it's not necessary, but I personally prefer `bool result = (int_value != 0);` for readability

Comment: @Steve Permitted by my aesthetic sense, yes. I have amended the formulation – a bit.

Comment: @satuon You’re free to do that but I shun redundant parentheses. They provide visual clutter and detract from the clarity of the code. Designers call this [negative space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space) and it’s the core concepts of presenting information in the least detracting way possible. (The Wikipedia explanation isn’t good, by the way. It makes it sound as if negative space’s main use was to create illusions.)

Comment: @Konrad: everyone has their own level of being able to work out operator precedence. Of course any vaguely decent programmer *can* figure it out, but I think there are plenty of cases where it's genuinely questionable what proportion can figure it out faster than they would have done had there been parentheses around the trickier parts. And "tricky" depends entirely on audience. Do you run static analysis to ensure that your code strictly contains parens only when they alter the meaning of the expression? ;-) In this case I agree it's readable without, but I think not in all cases.

Comment: @Steve You’re right but there’s no slippery slope (in fact, that’s a classical logical fallacy): sometimes the choice of parentheses may be a judgement call but in others it clearly isn’t – and visual clutter *is* a problem to readability. (I don’t think you were implying that slippery slope but it could be read that way.)

Comment: @Konrad: as an aside, the slippery slope is a *logical* fallacy, but a psychological truth. Humans exhibit various temporal inconsistencies, and "not too much worse than before" is one of them. Visual clutter is a problem in readability, but I don't find either `result = (a != b)` or `(a * b) + c` to be visually cluttered. Clearly we agree that explicit and shorter is hands-down winner, but explicit and longer is frequently better than implicit and shorter. In this example I'm about equally happy with and without the parens, I think they're both entirely readable.

Comment: @Steve That’s a statement I can agree with.

Answer (score 9):

That's between you and your compiler, but Microsoft thinks you should write:

```
i != 0
```

in preference to either:

```
(bool)i
```

or

```
static_cast<bool>(i)
```

Possible reasons for preferring it include:

- this conversion doesn't act like other narrowing conversions, that take a modulus,
- the implict conversions to bool are also a bit controversial: plenty of people prefer to do `if (buf != NULL)` or `if (buf != 0)` in preference to `if (buf)` after a call to `malloc`,
- the comparison is both shorter and clearer.

Comment: About your second point: I for one believe that it’s fundamentally different to write a test `if (ptr_value)` from writing a test `if (int_value)` – the first is OK (in my little world) because it tests a *state* for validity while the second isn’t.

Comment: @Konrad: fair enough. You could have an integer that behaves analogously to a pointer in that respect - 0 *is* a special placeholder meaning "nothing", after all. But modern arithmetic has tamed it into being just another value, so you're quite right that integer 0 often doesn't mean "no" in the way that null pointers do.

Comment: "Microsoft thinks you should write" -- this is a rather bold statement, do you have a source for this?

Comment: @JasonS: I don't think it's bold. The compiler warns you away from one but not the other. I don't necessarily mean to imply that the compiler's "opinion" is one that the whole company would defend to the death, though, merely a preference that the company's product expresses.

Comment: ah, then you mean the Microsoft compiler produces warnings in both of the other cases?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it happens when you explicitly cast it (i think it was a performance warning?), but I usually use code like this to avoid any warnings:

```
int i;
bool b = (0!=i);
```

This never gives warnings.

Answer (score -1):

I do as someone already posted:

```
bool result = int_value != 0;
```

It's the easier way imo and the it's more intuitive than trying to cast the integer to bool.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please keep in mind that this is a Q&A site, and not a forum. Do not post an answer to say that you agree with another answer. Once you have enough reputation, you can express approval by upvoting.