# Check if element exists in C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find if a given key exists in a C++ std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939953/how-to-find-if-a-given-key-exists-in-a-c-stdmap)

In C++, how can I check if there is an element with a key?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Hardly. Learn the difference between a key and a value.

Comment: Actually, the title of that question is misleading, it is indeed about finding whether a given key exists in a std::map.

Comment: @Tomalak: Upon rereading the question and all answers, I am reasonably sure that it is a duplicate. Although the title is inaccurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (myMap.find(key) != myMap.end())
{ // there is such an element
}
```

See the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) for `std::map::find`

Comment: +1 (though I wouldn't recommend cplusplus.com to language newcomers).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: are you sure that OP is a newcomer? And what would you recommend instead?

Comment: I am curious , what is so bad about cplusplus? I use it quite often to understand small bits.

Comment: The question rather gives it away.

Comment: @RickoM: cplusplus.com is notoriously error-ridden, and its tutorials are misleading (even for tutorials). I use it myself as a "reminder" reference, but I know C++ well enough to spot the mistakes, and absolutely would not recommend it.

Answer (score 8):

Try to find it using the `find` method, which will return the `end()` iterator of your map if the element is not found:

```
if (data.find(key) != data.end()) {
    // key is found
} else {
    // key is not found
}
```

Of course you shouldn't `find` twice if you need the value corresponding to the given key later. In this case, simply store the result of `find` first:

```
YourMapType data;
...
YourMapType::const_iterator it;
it = data.find(key);
if (it != data.end()) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```