# Can't cast int to bool

Tags: c#, casting, int, boolean

I'm facing the problem that C# in my case can't cast the number 1 to bool. In my scenario `(bool)intValue` doesn't work. I get an `InvalidCastException`. I know I can use `Convert.ToBoolean(...)` but I'm just wondering it doesn't work. Any explanation for this?

My code is

```
if (actualValueType.Name == "Boolean" || setValueType.Name == "Boolean")
{
   if ((bool)actualValue != (bool)setValue)
   ...
}
```

Comment: `int` and `bool` are entirely different things in C#, and C# is known for being a very strongly-typed language.

Comment: Why not just write `myvar != 0`?

Comment: Also, why not check directly actualValue is bool && setValue is bool?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`int` and `bool` can't be converted implicitly (in contrast to C++, for example).

It was a **concious decision made by language designers** in order to save code from errors when a number was used in a condition. Conditions need to take a `boolean` value explicitly.

It is not possible to write:

```
int foo = 10;

if(foo) {
  // Do something
}
```

Imagine if the developer wanted to compare foo with 20 but missed one equality sign:

```
if(foo = 20) {
  // Do something
}
```

The above code will compile and work - and the side-effects may not be very obvious.

Similar improvements were done to `switch`: you cannot fall from one case to the other - you need an explicit `break` or `return`.

Comment: But I get an exception thrown... Is it not better to get a compiler error? Besides that why can I fall through in another program switch(var) { case "bla": case "bla2": break; default: break; }

Comment: In your switch you've just assigned 2 cases to one block of code - I'm talking about switch(x) { case "A": Console.Write("A"); case "B": Console.Write("B"); break; }. C++ equivalent will print "AB" in the console.

Comment: A compiler exception is better than a runtime error that doesn't throw an exception, which would be the case of `if (foo = 20)` if `int` values were castable to `bool`. With the compiler exception, you know about the problem immediately and you fix your code. With the runtime error, you may spend hours or days trying to figure out why your if-block always runs, even when `foo` doesn't equal 20.

Comment: I get an runtime exception and NOT a compiler error which would be better. This is what I ment.

Comment: @theknut - this is because you're doing casting which can only be checked at run-time. Compiler doesn't have enough information at compile-time to help you in your case.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki, that is not correct, it would be possible to check if setValue would not have been declared an object

Comment: @UrbanEsc - But since it is declared as object it is not possible to check. I was talking about this specific case.

Comment: Stumbled on this just now while searching other. Notice how, as usual, they made a stupid decision: do you want to avoid lateral effects in if? Give an error at compile time about it, instead of breaking tens of years of programmer's habits.

Comment: There's a difference between casting and implicit conversion.  I would expect it to not allow implicit conversion, but not casting (going out of my way to say, yes I know you're not a bool, pretend to be) sounds like a short coming of the language.

Answer (score 59):

There's no need to cast:

```
bool result = intValue == 1;
```

From the docs:

> The inclusion of bool makes it easier to write self-documenting code
>
> a bool value is either true or false

[1.2.1 Predefined Types (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664635%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @theknut `if ((actualValue>0) != (setValue>0))`, assuming `int > 0 = true` and `int < 0 = false`.

Comment: Actually the correct is `bool result = intValue != 0;` since False is 1 and True everything but 0.

Comment: @shadow I think you mean "False is 0 and True everything but 0" rather than "False is 1 and True everything but 0"

Answer (score 41):

```
bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(0);
```

Will convert 0 and null to false and anything else to true.

Answer (score 1):

"In other languages, false is equivalent to 0 and true is equivalent to 1, but this is not possible in the C# language."

I have to admit I thought false was zero and true was !false....

```
int fred = 2;

if (fred == true)
{
    printf("fred is true");
}
```

will certainly print fred is true

Answer (score 0):

In other languages, false is equivalent to 0 and true is equivalent to 1, but this is not possible in the C# language.

Comment: I know this. The question is: Why?!

Comment: @Jacob: Actually, in most languages false is equal to 0 and true is equal to any non-zero value.

Comment: @Yuck I was wondering if he is really right. I agree with you!

Comment: @theknut - Because bool is a type that is either true or false and not an integer type with slapped on truth-i-ness.

Comment: I understand. But still... I just want to know why they can't implement it. It's not slapped on truth-i-ness. It's a simple if else to implement, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, `bool` is actually a [`Boolean` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx), so it's not just represented as a 1 or 0 internally. It seems like the creators of the language went for an explicit over implicit approach overall with the language. To accomplish what you're trying to do (to effectively cast 1 to `true` and 0 to `false`), do this:

```
if (intValue == 1) {
    // do something
} else if (intValue == 0) {
    // do something else
} else {
    // invalid bool
}
```

You could also drop the last else clause and do the typical C-language thing and let `intValue == 0` be equivalent to `false` and anything else is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably repeating others here but you cant cast int to bool because **int is not a bool**. It is an int. Who would have thought? ;-)

You need to create a new bool based on your int value, and the already posted "myvar != 0" seems good enough.

Also where do you get your exception? Running the following code will most certainly produce a compiler error:

```
int myIntValue = 0;
bool myBoolValue = (bool)myIntValue;
```

You must be doing some generic stuff which is not shown in your question.

Comment: No generic stuff at all. It's the same code as seen above. setValue is 1 und actualValue is true. During run I get the exception.

Comment: if setValue is declared as an int you should get a compiler error in the (bool)setValue line! "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'" - please post the complete method (including variable declarations)

Comment: setValue is obejct. Thats why the compiler doesn't bring an error.

Comment: I see. Fix your code like this: if (actualValueType.Name == "Boolean" **&&** setValueType.Name == "Boolean")

Comment: No I don't. Functionallity will be lost. I want to figure out if one of them is bool.

Comment: if one of them is not a bool you will always get an exception then, i am not sure if that is what you want

Comment: I no longer do it this way. I use Convert.ToBoolean(setValue).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cast two values variable into bool like var that holds (1 and 2 and want to return 1 for false and 2 for true ) i suggest :

```
//in the end of method or something :
return w == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator like below, instead of a cast.
    bool b = true;
    int i = 1;

```
// bool to int
i = b == true ? 1 : 0;
// int to bool
b = i > 0 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is not to have to type the `!= 0` in `if (foo != 0)`, you could make an extension method for the int type and do something like `if (foo.IsNonZero())`.

If C# allowed for extension properties, you would be able to write `if (foo.IsNonZero)` without the parentheses, which in my opinion would read more clearly than the original `if (foo != 0)`, but sadly, that is currently not the case.

You're probably better off with the previously suggested `Convert.ToBoolean(foo)` either way, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a pathfinding, for learning purposes. I need to randomly block some nodes as walkable/blocked.

Here's a simple solution I came up with:

```
int block = Random.Range(0, 10) + 1;
node.blocked = (block % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
```