# Can't cast 0 or 1 to a boolean in C#

Tags: c#, casting, compiler-errors, boolean

I was playing around with type casting earlier today, and came across a something interesting. The C# compiler is unable to cast `0` or `1` to a boolean data type. For example:

```
bool b = (bool)0;
```

would return false (if it was able to compile).

There doesn't seem to be any loss of information here, so my question is, is there some specific reason the C# compiler doesn't let you do this?

Comment: "would return false (if it was able to compile)" would be a tautology if it were a tautology.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571312/cant-cast-int-to-bool

Comment: Use `Convert.ToBoolean()` for "loosely-typed" conversions.

Answer (score 6):

Because in order for your cast to work, *every* `int` would have to be able to be cast to `bool`, not just 1 and 0. The decision to not allow all integers to be treated as boolean values was done purposefully, to remove the possibility for the kinds of errors this allowance accounts for in languages where it is allowed, e.g. C and C++.

Comment: Why not just make it so all non 0 integers are true? Like C and C++?

Comment: like -345 for instance?

Comment: So, still the question remains. If every int were able to cast to a bool, there would be a loss of information on all but two values. It should still work if I explicitly cast it, because I'm acknowleding that I might loose some information.

Comment: It won't work if you explicitly cast it, because there is no explicit conversion defined. That it *should* work is your opinion, one which the language designers did and do not share.

Comment: See the linked dupe for an expansion of the argument against what you propose, @Cole and Ro K.

Comment: It comes down to compiler rules.  But there are several answers already pointing out methods you can use.

Comment: If I had to guess? Because Eric Lippert decided that 3 - 3 isn't false, that's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson If you want `c != 0`, just type that. It's easier to understand and indicates what you really want.

Comment: @Michael I get the reason behind no implicit cast, but why not even with an explicit cast? That's what I was getting at.

Comment: @Cole: I'm only speculating, but the language designers may not have seen a need for it, given BCL functions like `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Comment: I actually seem to recall that at a low-level, every bit pattern that isnt all zeroes stored in a `bool` **does** count as `true`. (It's there in the CLR specs somewhere.) This also causes some amount of fun when you combine bools with bitwise operators. I should fish out the question where that was discussed. As in, it is an implementation detail, but it can also be made to leak if you try.