# c#:Cannot implicity convert 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#-4.0, int, boolean

I'm new to programming. Could you help me with this error, please.

```
        static int cif2(int a)
        {
            do
            {
                if (a % 10) s++;
                a = a / 10;
            } while (a > 0);

            return s;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            do
            {
                ok = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
                    if (cif2(v[i]) >cif2(v[i + 1]))
                    {
                        int t = v[i];
                        v[i] = v[i + 1];
                        v[i + 1] = t;
                        ok = false;
                    }
            } while (!ok);
```

The error is pointing at if(a%10) but I can't see the problem here..

Comment: `a%10` returns an integer value. Integer can not be passed as a condition in `if`. It has to be boolean. What is the reason you are putting `a%10` in `if` ?

Comment: Why don't you declare `ok` anywhere? It should probably  be `if (a%10!=0)`, unlike other languages, `int` is not implicitly convertible to `bool`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't cast int to bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571312/cant-cast-int-to-bool)

Comment: The thing is that when I did it with my teacher, it worked. It's a sorting algorithm that sort numbers after the last number(sorry for my bad english)   ex: 1 2 56 31 22 24 52 , it will sort just like 1, 56, 31, 24, 2, 22, 52

Answer (score 0):

You should have `cif2` method as following.

```
static int cif2(int a)
{
    var s = 0;
    do
    {
        if (a % 10 != 0) //I am not sure of your requirement. The other option would be if(a % 10 == 0)
        { 
            s++;
        }
        a = a / 10;
    } while (a > 0);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: + i forgot to initiate s=0