# Convert bool to int in a Radio Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have never used a Radio Button before. I have a datagridview and I added 3 radio buttons to my form to populate all the data, the is active data and not active data.
This is what I am calling for the is active radio button, but it doesn't want to convert the bool to an int.

```
private void rbIsActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = txtSearchText.Text;
    //bool sActive = true;
    //int i = sActive ? 1 : 0;
    bool IsActive = Convert.ToInt32(rbIsActive.Checked);
    var listBooks = GetBooks(searchText);
    grdBooks.DataSource = listBooks;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of output are you trying to achieve?  Just a 1 or 0 for true or false?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to convert a `bool` to an `int` then assign to a `bool`

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571312/cant-cast-int-to-bool

Comment: *what am I doing wrong?* Trying to convert what's already a boolean into an int to assign it to a boolean. `bool IsActive = rbIsActive.Checked;`. And possibly using three radiobuttons when a single checkbox would suffice. IsActive can only have two values, right? (Active, or True, and not Active, or False). That's specifically what a checkbox says: It's either checked (true) or not checked (false).

Comment: remove "Convert.ToInt32" from your code. and it'll work.

Comment: @maccettura i am trying to populate all the "true" values

Comment: @Stavm i get this error " Error converting data type nvarchar to tinyint."

Comment: What are you trying to populate with "true" values?  And when you say "true" does that mean the boolean value of `true` or the string representation "true"?

Comment: @SMG "Error converting data type nvarchar to tinyint" comes from your database not C#. this is a bad question i'm finding myself trying to guess your question, please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Don't convert to an int, mainly because you're assign it to a bool variable.

Comment: So how am i suppose to convert it if i want to show "true"?

Comment: @SMG IsActive.ToString() ?

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
bool IsActive = Convert.ToInt32(rbIsActive.Checked);
```

you convert a boolean to an int and are trying to save it into a bool variable. This obviously can not work.