# C++ Map : manipulate map inside map

Tags: c++, dictionary, mapping, nested-map

I'm more used to a single map and not to nested map. So I have serious difficulty understanding how to deal with this.

**Remark: Please don't request me to use multimap or boost,I'm restricted to use this structure**

In C++ STL map, i have a definition like this

```
map<string, map<string, string>> exploration; // country --> state --> city
```

The first map represent a pair of key(country) and value as tree structure `map<string, string>` which represent there respective state and city.

I know how to populate this structure manually **(hard coding)** like so:

```
exploration["Canada"]["Ontario"] = "Toronto";
```

**Problem :**

Later the data showed above will be entred by the user :

`> Canada Ontario Toronto`

`> Canada Alberta Edmonton`

`> USA Washington Seatle`

`> USA Nevada Las-Vegas`

So if I apply this logic to my example above, this is wrong since map does not accept duplicate keys

Illustration **(wrong)** :

```
exploration["Canada"]["Ontario"] = "Toronto";
exploration["Canada"]["Alberta"] = "Edmonton";
```

Illustration **(What I'm looking for)** :

```
exploration["Canada"]["Ontario"] = "Toronto";
                     ["Alberta"] = "Edmonton";

        Canada
          **
         *  *     
        *    *
     Ontario Alberta
       *        *
      *          *
   Toronto     Edmonton
```

My hypothetical solution,

```
> Canada Ontario Toronto
```

**1 case**: If the country(Canada) does not exist in exploration structure,I add it as well as the province and its city.

**2 case**: If the country(Canada) exist, so I add Ontario and Toronto a long side the data entered before.

Any indications, ideas or hints are welcomed.

Comment: Well, what you put as the wrong illustration is, in fact, correct. It will create one map for the `Canada` key containing another map as its value. The latter then contains two keys.

Comment: I think this link might be able to help you : 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/113056/

Comment: "So if I apply this logic to my example above, this is wrong since map does not accept duplicate keys". What is the actual problem you are seeing? Compilation errors? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: What I mean by wrong is I don't want the key Canada to be inserted every time, but juste the inside map in case the country exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is quite right. Looking at the code below (in C++11 but the same reasoning applies to previous versions), you can see that each country is only inserted once in the `exploration` map.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, map <string, string> > exploration;
    exploration["Canada"]["Ontario"] = "Toronto";
    exploration["Canada"]["Alberta"] = "Edmonton";
    exploration["USA"]["Washington"] = "Seattle";
    exploration["USA"]["Nevada"] = "Las Vegas";

    cout << "Number of keys: " << exploration.size() << endl;

    for (auto country : exploration) {
        for (auto city : country.second)
            cout << country.first << ":" << city.first << " -> " << city.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number of keys: 2
Canada:Alberta -> Edmonton
Canada:Ontario -> Toronto
USA:Nevada -> Las Vegas
USA:Washington -> Seattle
```

Let's go step by step to understand what is going on:

1. `map<string, map <string, string> > exploration`: Defines a map whose keys are strings and its values are other maps. It is empty so far.
2. `exploration["Canada"]["Ontario"] = "Toronto"`: First it checks that `Canada` does not exist in the `exploration map`. Hence a mapping is created linking `Canada` to an empty map. Now, a mapping from `Ontario` to `Toronto` is created inside the `exploration["Canada"]` map.
3. `exploration["Canada"]["Alberta"] = "Edmonton"`: Since the `Canada` key already exists in `exploration`, no need to create it again. It will just map `Alberta` to `Edmonton` in the already created map.

The same reasoning applies to the `USA` map. This way, there will be no duplicated keys even with nested maps. C++ is great.

Comment: do I need to create another function which verify if Canada(country) exist or not,  or it done by map automatically?

Comment: @DavidEdgar no need. C++ automatically creates the inner map when it detects the keys doesn't exist. The example I wrote works perfectly.

Comment: what if in case I want to check if a specific city exist in a country. Like check fi Toronto is inserted in Canada. how to deal with this?

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939953/how-to-find-if-a-given-key-exists-in-a-c-stdmap). You can do something like `if (exploration["Canada"].find("Toronto") != exploration.end())` to check whether `Toronto` is inside `Canada`.

Comment: I'm putting things together right now, so later I'll give it a try. i appreciate your help @Matheus Portela.

Comment: @MatheusPortela `exploration["Canada"].end()`

Comment: @super good catch. `if (exploration["Canada"].find("Toronto") != exploration["Canada"].end())` is the proper conditional.

Comment: `exploration["Canada"].count()` is even more appropriate to avoid extra look up on first `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two cities in the same state, so you really need `map<string, map<string, set<string>>>`

But what you have before that will already work.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>> countries;

    countries["Canada"]["Ontario"].insert("Toronto");
    countries["Canada"]["Ontario"].insert("Something else");
    countries["Canada"]["Alberta"].insert("Edmonton");


    for (const auto& country : countries) {
        std::cout << "Country: " << country.first << "\n";
        for (const auto& statePair : country.second) {
            std::cout << "State: " << statePair.first << "\n";
            for (const auto& city : statePair.second) {
                std::cout << "City: " << city << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Will output

```
Country: Canada
State: Alberta
City: Edmonton 
State: Ontario
City: Something else
City: Toronto
```

EDIT:

In relation to your follow up question, this should get you there:

```
using CountryMap = std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>>;
bool countryContainsCity(const CountryMap& countryMap, const std::string& country, const std::string& city)
{
    for (const auto& country : countryMap[country]) {
        for (const auto& statePair : country.second) {
            if (statePair.second.find(city)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if in case, I want to check if in some country(Canada) a city named Toronto exist or not. How to deal with it?

Comment: Good @dempzorz, I'll give it a try later +1