# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'?

Tags: c++, iterator, maps

I am trying to see if a particular key exists in `map` and if so then I want to increase its value by 1. But while running the program I am getting the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  map::at

Why is it going `out_of_range` can someone help?

> b is a map in this function.
> itr is an iterator for accessing its elements

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
        ct=0;
        cin>>a[i];
        for(itr=b.begin();itr!=b.end();itr++)
        {
            if(itr->first==a[i])
                ct++;
            else
                continue;
        }
        if(!ct)
        {
            b.at(a[i])++;
        }
        else
        {
            b.insert(pair <int,int>(a[i],1));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **a** is just an integer array.

Comment: see [this page about std::map::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), maybe `a[i]` is not in map's keyset, thus result in the `out_of_range` exception.

Comment: `if(!ct)` should presumably be `if(ct)`. Note your for loop should probably just be replaced with `std::map::find`

Comment: The whole outer `i` loop body can be replaced by `cin >> a[i]; auto p = b.insert({a[i],0}); p.first++;`. It will be also more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this whole thing in just 3-4 lines :

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> a[i];
    ++b[a[i]];
}
```

The [subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will automatically insert `{a[i], 0}`, if `a[i]` is not there as a key in map `b`. Then incrementing it makes it equivalent to your code where you try to insert a pair `{a[i], 1}`.

---

**What was wrong with your approach :**

The condition that you used before doing `b.at(a[i])++` is wrong. It should have been `if (ct)` not `if (!ct)`.

[*Improvements*]

You could have put a `break` on finding `itr->first == a[i]` to be true. But still it's complexity was time `O(n)`. That defies the very purpose of using `std::map` instead of `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`. You can perform that operation in logarithmic time complexity if you used [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) instead. (More methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939953/how-to-find-if-a-given-key-exists-in-a-c-stdmap).)